# Conversion to hh:mm (24-hour clock format) fails to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, format, timespan

Here is the information about my development environment:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
- .NET Framework 4.0
- MongoDB 3.0.0
- MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714

I have C# code that need to display a duration of time as `hh:mm` (24-hour clock format)

I tried to use the `TimeSpan.FromHours` function.

```
String aTimSpn = TimeSpan.FromHours(70 - 19.083).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

The problem is that the aforementioned code gives a result of `"02:55"`, but I was expecting `"50:55"` which would be 50 hours and 55 minutes.

How can I implement the code in such a way that I get the `"50:55"` result?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TotalHours` and `Minutes` (instead of immediately call `ToString`), and cast the `TotalHours` to `int`:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(70 - 19.083);
String aTimSpn = ((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString();
```

`Hours` will give your `TotalHours mod 24` (casted to `int`) result (which is 2) instead of the real total hours.

`TotalHours` will give you result including the fraction. Thus, use `(int)` casting to make it integer (`50` instead of `50.917`).